# Network issue with IP cameras

Tags: switch, ip, cable, power-over-ethernet

The network consists of 7 UBNT G3 IP cameras a netgear 16 Gigabit port switch and a Windows 7 NVR that is running Blue Iris (I ran UniFi Video and Xprotect Essential with same results, so it is not the software).

All cables are under 200 feet. 3 cables are over 150 feet, 1 is ~130 feet, 1 is ~100feet, 1 is ~75 feet and the last one is in the same office as the NVR so very short.

All cables were created from a spool (replaced camera side connectors twice) one connector was replaced at the switch side, will replace a few more at a later date.

Switch and router have been replaced by other brands with same results.

Each camera is running on the supplied POE injector that came with the camera.

All cameras are on static local IPs.

The issue:
After startup the cameras will run for a random amount of time (from a few minutes to several hours) and will start to lose the connection (reseting the IP) this will happen 3 - 5 times and than they will all go down one by one (the camera is still on but no access to web GUI or SSH) after unplugging the LAN cable and leaving the POE cable plugged in the cameras will come back online and will show that they were never powered off, so they get enough power.

The only camera that hasn't exhibited this behavior is the one thats directly in the office on the shortest cable.

The logs for the affected cameras show that eth0 is down and then PHY up?

I am out of my depth here:(

Could a bad cable/connector cause all these issues?

Comment: Have you looked at the test results that your cable installer provided?

Comment: You made the cables yourself? Pairing and twisting are AOK? Any testing done?

Comment: @Zac67 Yes the cables were made by me, I used this diagram "B" https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--jHmXhCpY--/c_fit,fl_progressive,q_80,w_636/18lqf3uc4wj6hgif.gif I just transferred some files over the cable to see if they work. I know i'm a noob in networking.

Comment: @RonMaupin I was the one creating the cables from a spool, and connectors, i created them at work as well and we move terabytes of data per week with no issues, so not sure what could be the cause here, not even sure how to properly test them. :(

Comment: That's not usually a good idea. Are the cameras using Gigabit or just 100 Mbit/s? Since the data flow is into the switch, have you looked at the port (error) counters on the switch?

Comment: You need to test the cables to see if they pass the test suite for the cable category. You need to use something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/Fluke-Networks-DTX-1800-120-CableAnalyzer/dp/B00026V6CI/ref=sr_1_11?ie=UTF8&qid=1499709577&sr=8-11&keywords=fluke+network+tester). You must also use the correct cable and connector types. Solid-core cable and wall plates for the horizontal cable (<=90 meters), and stranded cable and connectors for the patch cords (<= 10 meters, combined for both ends).

Comment: @Zac67 Well now i Know that its a bad idea :(, all cameras start out as 100 Mbit and auto negotiate to 10Mbit (real network throughput is about 6.7Mbits on average. never saw anything over 8Mbits ever)

Comment: @RonMaupin Understood thank you! I will look for a more affordable option

Comment: "Start out as 100 Mbit and auto negotiate to 10 Mbit" doesn't make too much sense. What's the indicated link speed? The actually throughput doesn't matter too much.

Comment: @Zac67 When running Unifi Video suit/software the settings screen shows the cameras start out as 100Mbits and then switch to 10Mbits after Unifi Video starts managing the camera, The only lights on the switch that are ever lit are the 100Mbits.

Comment: The software is probably getting so many errors due to bad cabling that it is trying to slow down the speed. With modern network speed and frequencies, you need to leave cabling to experienced professionals. There are full test suites for each cable category, and you do not have the experience or equipment to properly install. An installer will give you a test report, and will fix any problems before giving you the cabling.

Comment: That's just the application & has no impact. When making your own cables - even for 100 Mbit/s - you have to take care that you match the pairs to either TIA-568A or TIA-569B. Check the colors and note that the outer pairs are on each edge and the inner pairs are nested. Use Cat-5 connectors suited for the cable (solid or stranded) and the cable gauge. Try to preserve the original twist as much as possible, don't under or overtwist. My guess is that you mixed the pairs and the FCS counter on the switch keeps increasing...

Comment: @RonMaupin Ok understood:( seems this is going to be a problem, aside from running new cables would you have any other suggestions? I understand I need to test the cables, but if i find an issue, in your experience could it be fixed with replacing connectors? Im just grasping at straws here since removing cables isnt an option:(

Comment: @RonMaupin The low bandwidth is not necessarily a problem - the stream could be really so low.

Comment: @Zac67 Understood, will go through the cables again and make sure i didn't make a mistake? again im an idiot in networking, would the FCS have such a devastating effect on the network?

Comment: A cable installer may be able to fix what you have run, but there are some things to consider. When installing the solid-core (it is isn't it? Stranded cable will no work at the distances you quote) horizontal cable, if you exceed the maximum pulling tension or minimum bend radius, you can permanently damage the cabling so that it will never pass the test suite.

Comment: @RonMaupin this is the cable used: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0058TZDGY/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: @RonMaupin there aren't any sever bends, the angles are all very gentle, I had a lot of room to work with so tried not to kink or even have anything remotely damaging to the cable.

Comment: If you ran that cable indoors, it is going to be illegal. You are only allowed 50' of outdoor cable to run inside from the outside. You cannot use outdoor cable inside a building. If you ever get inspected by a building inspector or fire marshal, they could red-tag the building, fine you and not let anyone in until the situation is corrected. This is a life/safety problem, and deaths from smoke inhalation in the event of a fire could result in criminal prosecution.

Comment: @RonMaupin understood, the 6 cameras are all outside (parking lot, walkways, that sort of thing)

Comment: OK, as long as you don't have more than 50' inside the building. As I wrote, you should consult an experienced cable install, preferably BICSI certified. The installer may be able to fix your installation.

Comment: @RonMaupin Just spoke with the owner and the inspection was done on the cables by a fire marshal and some other entity (city engineer maybe?) it all passed. also an update after unplugging the 2 cameras that looked like they have wonky connectors at the switch side, the system stabilized, still keeping an eye on it.

Comment: OK. I posted an answer so that you can accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. You should still get all the cables checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a cabling problem. You should consult an experienced, certified installer to see if your cabling can be fixed. Get the proper reports and put them on file for later reference.